# Symfony2: Cache a "Class Loader" with OpCache

Tags: php, symfony, apc, opcache

`PHP` features a new code caching module called [OPCache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php). Symfony2 [recommended to use](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/cache_class_loader.html) `ApcClassLoader` (based on [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)) or `XcacheClassLoader` (based on [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)) to cache the mapping from a class to its containing file. My server (Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.6) use `OpCache`.

1. Is there an alternative "cache mapping" for `OpCache`? I have not found.
2. I can use `APC` and `OpCache` together (I could use ApcClassLoader)? I think not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usage of APC makes sense up to PHP version 5.4.
But even with 5.4 it is not fully compatible.
From PHP 5.5 on, it's better to use [APCu](http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu).

As of PHP 5.5 the Zend Opcache is a part of the core PHP distribution.
You may combine it with APCu.

Calls to the old APC functions will be emulated: `apc_*()`-> `apcu_*()`.
"APC emulation" will show up in phpinfo(), when the APCu ext is loaded.

[image]

So given PHP 5.6 with OpCache and APCu the SF2 ApcClassLoader should work.

The answer for question 1:
The OpCache is not a full blown cache, like APC, it's a simple opcode cache with some optimization steps. And it's not a userland cache - "just" an internal cache, speeding the processing of PHP up.

Comment: should work? ok , I'll try it I'll let you know. Meanwhile upvote for helpful information.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, using memcache makes sense. A memory storage is hard to beat performance wise. Additionally, the Opcache might need some tuning for full performance, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382615/apc-apcu-opcache-performance-poor